# Looking for VBA equivalent for Strright

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, lotusscript

Looking for a VBA equivalent for LotusScript's Strright. The snippet is to concatenate error messages into one cell.

[LotusScript Strright](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/LSAZ_STRRIGHT.html)

```
'Meera's error message code
ReDim Preserve errormsg(i)
errormsg(i) = "Field Required"
IsError = True

...
errormsg(i) = "Invalid Date"
etc...

If IsError = True Then
   tmpMsg = ""
   For Each v In errormsg
       tmpMsg = tmpMsg + "," + v
   Next v
   Cells(Row, 8).Value = strright(tmpMsg, ",")      'LotusScript
End If
```

Comment: `Instr()` and `Mid()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Join()`

```
If IsError = True Then
   Cells(Row, 8).Value = Join(errormsg, ",")
End If
```

or use this pattern:

```
If IsError = True Then
   Dim sep
   tmpMsg = ""
   For Each v In errormsg
       tmpMsg = tmpMsg + sep + v
       sep = ","
   Next v
   Cells(Row, 8).Value = tmpMsg
End If
```